# Cloning Input Fields with Unique IDs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form that I would like to have an user be able to add as many items to as they need. However, certain items require an AJAX call to retrieve information from a database, and that information be returned into fields. Currently, the replace destination is static, meaning that no matter what item calls the replace method, it will only change the first. I need it to change the one that called it. I've been stuck on this for three days, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Javascript:

```
ar uniqueId = 1;

function getAjax(seek, getId, destUrl, reset)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (seek=="")
    {
    document.getElementById(getId).innerHTML=reset;
    return;
    }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById('m_width' + getId).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",destUrl+seek,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}




$(function() {
     $('.addRow').click(function() {
         var copy = $("#original").clone(true);
         var formId = 'NewForm' + uniqueId;
         copy.attr('id', formId );
         copy.attr('name', formId );
         $('#item').append(copy);
         $('#' + formId).find('input,select,div').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + uniqueId); 
            $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + uniqueId); 
         });
         $('#NewForm').style.display = 'inline';
         uniqueId++;  

     });
});

$(function() {
     $('.removeRow').click(function() {
     $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <h3>item</h3>
    <div id="item" class="item" >
        <form action="" id="original">
        <input type="text" class="" id="hidden" value="">
        <select style="width: 160px" id="" name="" onchange="getAjax(this.value, 'm_width', 'm_width.php?media=','')">
                            <?php include 'includes/media.php'; ?>
        </select>

        <div id="m_width">
            <label for="media_color_size">Width: </label>
            <select id='media_color_size' style="width: 160px" disabled>
                <option value="">None</option>
            </select>
        </div>
      <select class="client" id="client" name="client" title="Client">
            <option>Client1</option>
            <option>Client2</option>
            <option>Client3</option>
            <option>Client4</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" class="removeRow" value="Remove Row"/>
    </div>
    </form>
    <input type="button" class="addRow" value="Add Row" />


</div>
```

and m_width.php:

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/dev/scripts/connect.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/dev/scripts/authorize.php';
authorize_user();
$media = trim(strip_tags($_GET["media"]));
$query = "SELECT distinct material_id, width FROM media WHERE material_id = $media;";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<label for='media_color_size'>Width: </label><br />";
echo "<select id='media_color_size' name='media_color_size' class='width' style='width: 160px'>";
echo "<option>Select Width</option>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<option value={$row['media_id']}>{$row['width']}</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
return;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you need to do without the use of unique IDs; there's too much unnecessary overhead. Class selectors would work fine. Here is my suggestion; if each form is inside a `div.item` element then use this to make the ajax call. **Plus**, you don't want to use inline JavaScript.

```
$('div.item form select').not('.client').on('change', function() {
    //save a reference to the select element that triggered the change event
    var that = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url:  '....',
        ....
        success: function() {
            //get the div.item ancestor of the select that triggered the change event
            var divItem = that.closest('div.item');

            //now change elements only within divItem
         }
    });
});
```

As you can see all this is accomplished without reference to any ID of any particular form. Therefore, you may not need to assign unique IDs to your forms.

**PROOF OF CONCEPT DEMO:**

```js
$('div.item form select').not('.client').on('change', function() {
  alert( $(this).closest( '.container' ).find( 'h3' ).text() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <h3>item 1</h3>
    <div id="item" class="item" >
        <form action="" class="original">
        <input type="text" class="hidden" value="">
        <select style="width: 160px" id="" name="">
             <option>One</option>
             <option>Two</option>
             <option>Three</option>
        </select>

        <div class="m_width">
            <label for="media_color_size">Width: </label>
            <select id='media_color_size' style="width: 160px" disabled>
                <option value="">None</option>
            </select>
        </div>
      <select class="client" name="client" title="Client">
            <option>Client1</option>
            <option>Client2</option>
            <option>Client3</option>
            <option>Client4</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" class="removeRow" value="Remove Row"/>
    </div>
    </form>
    <input type="button" class="addRow" value="Add Row" />
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h3>item 2</h3>
    <div id="item" class="item" >
        <form action="" class="original">
        <input type="text" class="hidden" value="">
        <select style="width: 160px" id="" name="">
             <option>One</option>
             <option>Two</option>
             <option>Three</option>
        </select>

        <div class="m_width">
            <label for="media_color_size">Width: </label>
            <select id='media_color_size' style="width: 160px" disabled>
                <option value="">None</option>
            </select>
        </div>
      <select class="client" name="client" title="Client">
            <option>Client1</option>
            <option>Client2</option>
            <option>Client3</option>
            <option>Client4</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" class="removeRow" value="Remove Row"/>
    </div>
    </form>
    <input type="button" class="addRow" value="Add Row" />
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h3>item 3</h3>
    <div id="item" class="item" >
        <form action="" class="original">
        <input type="text" class="hidden" value="">
        <select style="width: 160px" id="" name="">
             <option>One</option>
             <option>Two</option>
             <option>Three</option>
        </select>

        <div class="m_width">
            <label for="media_color_size">Width: </label>
            <select id='media_color_size' style="width: 160px" disabled>
                <option value="">None</option>
            </select>
        </div>
      <select class="client" name="client" title="Client">
            <option>Client1</option>
            <option>Client2</option>
            <option>Client3</option>
            <option>Client4</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" class="removeRow" value="Remove Row"/>
    </div>
    </form>
    <input type="button" class="addRow" value="Add Row" />
</div>
```

Comment: I really like the idea of not using unique IDs. However it seems that to use this I would need to have a block of script for each item (select:first, select:second, etc). Perhaps I am not seeing how to implement this correctly on a scaled version.

Comment: I have re-written the selector; there's something I overlooked. This version should work for all blocks.